# AS3 How to call an existing function?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to call a function(s) from different places. Dont have any luck so far.
This is the basic function. When i press a button it do something:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction1);
function myFunction1(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
   ///dosomeThing1
}
```

I have more than one button (myFunction2..3...4... etc)

but i wanted to exactly the same (myfunction1..2 etc) happen when i get a specific random number.
For example if random number = 1  >>> do myfunction1
if random number = 2  >>> do myfunction2

So i tried this:
(this code is at the top of the timelineframe)

```
function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
{
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}
var myrandomNumber = (randomRange(1, 6))
trace(myrandomNumber); //A number between 1 and 6
if (myrandomNumber == 1) {
    myFunction1(null); // i tried this (null) stuff
}
if (myrandomNumber == 2) {
    myFunction2();   // i tried also with just braces
}
```

etc.

the random number generation is alright, but i get errors all the time when i want to call a function  (if i give a simple >> smthng.gotoAndStop(x) command (instead of a function) it is fine)

**the whole code is in the timeline frame (no separate file)**

**the if statements are not inside in any function, just as you see here, it is ~kind of an "onLoad" stuff**

**The function works if i click on the button so it cant be the problem i guess, just is dont know how to call the same function from somewhere else?!? :-)**

anybody any ideas?
Really appreciate it!

Please leave examples! (Rookie programmer here! :-)

thanks
Ben

**Updates:**

after Neals advice (thanks)i tried this one:

```
function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
{
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}
var myrandom = (randomRange(1, 6))
trace(myrandom); //A number between 10 and 20
if (myrandom == 1) {

wbtungsten():void{
color2.redOffset   = 70;
color2.greenOffset = 0;
color2.blueOffset  = -100;
szin_wb_cam.szin_wb.transform.colorTransform = color2;
}
}
if (myrandom == 2) {
 // another something
}
```

and couple lines below:

```
nav_mc.navtungsten.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wbtungsten1);
private function wbtungsten1(e:MouseEvent)
{
wbtungsten();
}
```

In that case i get this errors:
Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 2, Line 23  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon. 
Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 2, Line 21  1078: Label must be a simple identifier. Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 2, Line 22 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before dot.

Comment: What errors do you get? Where do have the if statements? Inside a function? Is this all in the timeline or different .as files? Please update your question with this info instead of replying to this comment.

Comment: Since replacing the function with a different command works, the problem is not probably in any of what you have posted, but rather in the functions themselves. Can you post an example of these functions?

Comment: okay thanks!!! i updated the question :-)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error message you get.

Comment: okay everything is updated!

Comment: Your errors are on lines 21, 22 and 23. You are still not telling us what those specific lines look like (we cannot guess which ones just from your shown code). That said, I tried to hazard a working answer for you. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: this version is a dead end... Neal had suggest it but i  guees i misunderstud something... a wrote a comment below your help!
Could You please download the .fla and look at it?!  It is really simplified for troubleshooting!  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** 
Regarding : *"The function works if i click on the button"* but somehow you cannot call it using `myFunction1(null);` or just `myFunction1();`. This tells me your function looks something like this

```
function myFunction1(event:MouseEvent):void
```

because it is associated with mouse clicks it can only run via a "click" event being noticed. To be able able to run the function regardless of clicks **or** direct calling (eg: `myFunction1();`) then define as...

```
function myFunction1(event:Event = null):void
```

**(2)** 
I haven't tested your code but I would guess this section would cause a problem.

```
if (myrandom == 1) {

wbtungsten():void{
color2.redOffset   = 70;
color2.greenOffset = 0;
color2.blueOffset  = -100;
szin_wb_cam.szin_wb.transform.colorTransform = color2;
}
```

especially this line **`wbtungsten():void{`** ... what are you trying to achieve with it exactly? Creating a new function inside an `If` statement? Stop doing that, it doesn't work as you can see.

**Possible fix** : Something like below should work.

```
if (myrandom == 1) 
{
    color2.redOffset   = 70;
    color2.greenOffset = 0;
    color2.blueOffset  = -100;
    szin_wb_cam.szin_wb.transform.colorTransform = color2;

    wbtungsten(); //call the function called "wbtungsten"
}
```

**(3)** 
Regarding this quote:

> *"...but I wanted to exactly the same (myfunction1..2 etc) happen when I get a specific random number. For example if random number = 1 >>>
>   do myfunction1 if random number = 2 >>> do myfunction2"*

I'm a little confused about the link between these `myfunction1` and `wbtungsten1` and `wbtungsten();` etc etc. If what you're trying to achieve is that each random number affects `color2`'s red, green and blues offsets then you should do something like below :

```
if (myrandom == 1) 
{
    change_Color(70, 0, -100);
}   

if (myrandom == 2) 
{
    change_Color(10, 25, 5); //some other numbers for testing
}   

function change_Color(redNum:Number, greenNum:Number, blueNum:Number) : void
{
    color2.redOffset   = redNum;
    color2.greenOffset = greenNum;
    color2.blueOffset  = blueNum;

    szin_wb_cam.szin_wb.transform.colorTransform = color2;
}
```

What's happening above is you call the same function from each random number but you give the function different parameters (settings) to work with. Maybe the above function `change_Color` achieves what your **`wbtungsten():void{`** was trying to fulfill but I can't be sure.

> ...
>
> **Edit** :
>   Regarding *"It is pretty simple code now... .i dont get it why it isnt working"*

The problem is the structure of your code. Remember Flash Player processes code line by line downwards unless you make it "jump" to a later line. You have `if` statements that jumps straight into a function. Since the function references a variable that does not exist you will get a null. I can see you declared `var color2:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();` but the "jump" skipped over it so `color2.redOffset = 70;` means nothing to the compiler.

**Solution** : 
 
Put this line (shown below) before any `If` or `function` stuff. In your FLA, it becomes very top/first line of code (now everything else later knows what you mean by `color2` & no more `null` issues)...

```
var color2:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
```

Declare all your variables first before any other code that either adjusts those variables or goes to functions that use the variables. This way you force compiler to read (& understand) them before any further usage.

Optimal code structure should be :

1) **imports** - Any `Imports` are declared first at top of code
2) **variables** - Declare your variables. (if you think of a new one later just scroll back here to add it) 
3) **main code** - Instruction code involving variables & functions...
4) **functions** - Main code will reference or jump to here whenever need before returning to do next known line of instructions in **main code** at (3)..

Comment: VC.One thank You!
I tried solution ONE... 
I get this error:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at functioncall_fla::MainTimeline/wbtungsten()
 at functioncall_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: Solution 2 and 3 could work i guess but solution one is so simple and elegant... i dont understand why it isnt working...
I made a simplified version and uploaded here:

Comment: could anybody take a look!? Thanks!
It is pretty simple code now... .i dont get it why it isnt working

Comment: @BenthePhoto, does the additional info in new edit solve your issue?

Comment: okay after a quick test it looks like it is working!! :-)
Your answer was very helpfull!
I put the test code back to the "big file" and see what it does, when i get home!!!

Comment: Very thorough answer! Make sure to mark the green tick if you accept this as answered when the time comes

Comment: Okay VC.One thanks! It works!  Very helpful, very usefull help thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your function is expecting an event.

Do this instead:

```
myFunction1():void{
    //do stuff
}

addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,doSomethingHelper);

private function doSomethingHelper(e:MouseEvent){
    myFunction1();
}
```

**update**

I see in your updated code you are creating a function inside of an `if` block. That makes it inaccessible to the rest of your code. Don't do that.  It's your wbtungsten function. Create it elsewhere, then call it inside the `if` block like `wbtungsten();`

Comment: okay a tried it!

I get several error message listed below.....
(if i dont try to use this function stuff i dont get any errors...)
?!?!

Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 2, Line 21 1078: Label must be a simple identifier.


Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 2, Line 22 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before dot.

I get several errors.

Scene 1, Layer 'AS3', Frame 2, Line 23 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon.

Comment: And what is on line 23?

Comment: Again, at the bottom of your question (not in a comment) please post the code that you now have that is causing the errors. You say you tired it. Ok. Show me. And I'll try to see what is wrong. I just have to see it in context. And to clarify, all your code is in frame 2? Usually people have a specific layer called "code" and all the code goes on frame 1, not 2

Comment: frame 1 is the preload, everything else is on frame 2. Yes specific layer name as3. thanks